How to pronounce "adherent"?
I try to figure out how to pronounce "adherent" in American accent. According to Merriam-Webster, it should be ad-ˈhir-ənt . The first vowel should be the same as the vowel in "cat".
But according to Cambridge dictionary's US pronunciation, it should be /ədˈhɪr.ənt/, the same vowel sound as in "ago".
Which one is correct? Thanks

The vowel to my ear sounds somewhere between the vowel in "add" and the vowel in "ago".  The first syllable of the word is a very brief syllable and doesn't give the vowel much time to "open out".

Yes, exactly. I also feel it sounds between the vowel in "add" and the vowel in "ago". But which one is preferred in the US? I am asking this question because I live in the US.

I am a native speaker of AmE.  You have to find the mid-ground between those two vowels. Make it sound like "add" but very short, syncopated. Like abhorrent.

@TimR Thanks. I understand now. It is a very interesting phenomenon. This is basically the vowel sound Merriam-Webster provides. Also the first vowel sound in "additional" and "administer" is the same as that in adherent, right? I also need to find the mid-ground between those two vowels?

Yes, those first syllables are all brief.  The same approach applies.

Either pronunciation will likely be acceptable to many English speakers who are not pretentious or pedantic. Pronunciation can vary slightly from region to region. You may use either and will likely be understood equally in many cases.

Thanks. Is one preferred than the other in the US? I always feel Merriam-Webster provides very Americanized pronunciation, which is different from the more "neural pronunciation" provided by Cambridge dictionary's US pronunciation.
